# <p:focus> after page submit while staying on the same page does not work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like to use the Primefaces `p:focus` tag on a page that contains a form with input fields. Until the first commit the focus is set correctly. If I submit the form via a `p:commandButton` and return to the same page to show the error result (using FacesMessage messages), the focus is not defined (in Firefox the cursor blinks in the middle of nowhere).

How can I achieve a defined state of the focus? Can I choose which element has the focus after a submit?

Here are some code details:

The JSF page:

```
<p:panel header="Login">
    <h:form>
        <p:focus for="usernameInput" />
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:outputLabel for="usernameInput">User name</p:outputLabel>
            <p:inputText id="usernameInput" value="#{loginBean.username}" />
            <p:outputLabel for="passwordInput">Password</p:outputLabel>
            <p:password id="passwordInput" value="#{loginBean.password}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.login}" />
    </h:form>
</p:panel>
<div>
    <p:messages id="messages" globalOnly="false" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" closable="false" />
</div>
```

The relevant parts of the Java class:

```
public String login() {

    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    HttpServletRequest req =
            (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();

    try {
        req.login(username, password);
        return "/home?faces-redirect=true";
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        fc.addMessage(
                null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error",
                    "error message")));
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: try adding id to your panel: `<p:panel header="Login" id="myPanel">` and using `<p:focus context="myPanel"/>`

Comment: No - sorry - but after the submit the focus is still undefined.